# Find distance between root and any node in binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I am trying to write a code for finding distances between root and any node in binary tree. If the value of the node I am looking for is not in tree, I'll add it in tree and write its depth. I tried to write a code but somehow for root i get correct answer (depth=0) and for anything else I get value of depth = 1. I have been looking in code for quite a while now, so maybe you guys can help. Much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct b_tree t;

struct b_tree {
    int value;
    struct b_tree * right;
    struct b_tree * left;
};


int add(t **root, t *bam, int pom) {

    if ((*root) == NULL) {
        *root = bam;
        return pom;
    }
    else {
        if((*root)->value == bam->value){
            return pom;
        }
        else if((*root)->value > bam->value) {
            pom++;
            add(&(*root)->left, bam, pom);
        }

        else if ((*root)->value < bam->value) {
            pom++;
            add(&(*root)->right, bam, pom);
        }




    }

    return pom;
}



int main() {
    t *akt, *root = NULL;
    int x=1, pom=0, depth;

    while (x!=0){

        scanf("%d", &x);
        pom=0;
        akt = (t *)malloc(sizeof(t));
        akt->left = akt->right = NULL;
        akt->value = x;
        depth = add(&root, akt, pom);
        printf("%d\n", depth);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

When debugging, the code gets in a unusual cycle (??). if `pom` is the value represented as my depth from root to node, what it does is, it gets to the correct answer (depth of node is 3, pom=3), but when I try to return pom; for unknown reason (to me) pom is lowered always to 1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are discarding the values returned by recursive calls to `add()`. Change the calls to:

```
return add(&(*root)->left, bam, pom);
...
return add(&(*root)->right, bam, pom);
```